# Limit vertex weights on subdivided mesh - problem

Tags: rigging, export, subdivision-surface, .fbx, vertex-weights

I need to limit vertex weights to 4 for game engines, but I also need this with subdivided meshes - of which doesn't work.

Apparently Blender subdivides the mesh with a modifier, good, but it also multiplies the vertex weights even after you have limited vertex weights to 4 (I have troubleshooted and found the Subdivide modifier is causing the issue). Though the control hull has it's limits applied, the exported FBX will contain double the vertex weights due to the SDS modifier, rendering the Game Engine FBX useless for what I need.

How do I apply SDS to an FBX without destroying/overreaching the Vertex weight limit and still preserve morphs (applying SDS needs no morphs to do so)?

Comment: I'm sure it's me but I don't get what you mean by " limit vertex weights to 4 "... afaik, weights are set between 0 and 1...

Comment: 4 weight influences to single vertice. For example, 4 bones pulling on one vertice. Typical of facial rigs with armatures. There is a tool in blender that limits these influences to the highest influence pone weights and normalizes the rest to 0 on said vertice.